# Extract these JavaScript values using python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://www.watch.org/us/hello.m3u8",
    image: "noimage",
    width: 728,
    height: 400,
    autostart: true,
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'nodetail'
});
</script>
```

This is the thing that get when parsing website

```
url = url
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
script = str(soup.find_all("script")[-1])

pattern1 = re.compile("(\w+): '(.*?)'")
fields1 = dict(re.findall(pattern1, script))

pattern2 = re.compile("(\w+): (.*?)")
fields2 = dict(re.findall(pattern2, script))

findfile = fields1['file']
```

This is the thing I'm trying. But cannot get that file value :(

### Any help

```
m = re.search("file: \"([^\"]+)\"", script)
print m.group(1)
```

it worked with this. Thanks Iluvatar

One more help need

```
      <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="6RfMdMqZkkH88h026pcTaaEtxNCWrhiF6ACoxKXjjiI=";</script>
      <div id="mediaplayer_wrapper" style="position: relative; width: 468px; height: 375px;"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.teledunet.com/player.swf?id0=82895116945100" width="880" height="500" bgcolor="#000000" id="mediaplayer_Player" name="playlist_Player" tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object><div id="mediaplayer_jwpsrv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                  var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i) ? true : false);
                  if (iOS ==false) {
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer_Player").setup({
                      file: "rtmp://hello.hello.net/hello-live/hello_eng_high",
                      width: "728",
                      height: "400",
                      primary: "flash",
                      title: "hello",
                      stretching:"",
                      image: "noimage",
                      autostart: "true"
                    });
                  };          </script>
```

Unable to get this one. WHen trying that code it shows

```
print m.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

---

It also fixed by

```
script = str(soup.find_all("script")[0])
```

this...
Thanks....... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexes are always an option.

```
m = re.search("file: \"([^\"]+)\"", soup)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: It worked. But it not work with this response? Any idea? Please see the top question. I updated

Comment: What do you mean? If you're asking why your version didn't work, I didn't really look at it, but it's at least because you were using non-greedy match (`.*?`), so it would match nothing by default. Also you used single quotes instead of the double quotes that appear in your data.

Comment: No no your code worked. 100% working. I added new response. Please see my question again

Comment: I'm trying different scrap but it seems same kind of java script have. But u told code is not works for that. Any idea?

Comment: Hm, using the string you just posted it still works for me.

Comment: Oh I found the issue. It getting another script section from websource... :( Not correct posision

Comment: It fixed with script = str(soup.find_all("script")[0])

Comment: Using 0 gets the first occurrence, using -1 gets the last. If you know more about your page structure, you may want to use that. Or just check if it finds the file param before moving on.